# Entry only 1 and 0

Tags: c++

I would like validation only 1 and 0 in (while) but with this code I have an error.

```
do {
    printf("kostas :");
    gets(pinakasa[i].noshleia);
} while (pinakasa[i].noshleia != 1 || piakasa[i].noshleia != 0);
```

Comment: Please provide some [mre] (a complete program, with a `main`) in your question. Read [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). `gets` is obsolete and dangerous. Enable all warnings and debug info when compiling. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) use `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Try to find an integer `x` for which `x != 0 || x != 1` is not true. (Start with 0 and 1.)

Comment: In the `while` statement there is definitely a typo: `pinakasa` vs `piakasa`.

Comment: Spelling error. Also, In a do while loop, the first iteration will always occur so your first iteration has no validation applied to it.

Comment: FWIW, `gets` has been deprecated and removed from both C and C++.  You should avoid using it yourself and use either `cin` or `scanf`

Comment: Try saying your while-condition out loud. "*Repeat while x is not 1 or x is not 0*" (which means essentially "forever"). You probably want "*Repeat while x is not 1 and x is not 0*". However it won't solve the issue as you probably need to compare strings, not integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gets()` fills a `char[]` buffer with characters read in from `STDIN`.  You are trying to compare a `char*` pointer (what a `char[]` *decays* into) to an `int` value, which won't work.  You need to do a string comparison instead, for example:

```c
do {
    printf("kostas :");
    gets(pinakasa[i].noshleia);
}
while (
    (strcmp(pinakasa[i].noshleia, "1") != 0) &&
    (strcmp(pinakasa[i].noshleia, "0") != 0)
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! If i want same with characters e.g f and m?

Comment: Obviously, you would replace `"1"` and `"0"` with `"f"` and `"m"` as needed.

Comment: And if want dates by 1 to 30 days? :)

Comment: Then you will have to convert the string to an integer first, such as with `atoi()` or `sscanf()`, and then you can compare that to your desired values, `int day; do { ... day = atoi(pinakasa[i].noshleia); } while ((day < 1) || (day > 31));`